# Gyrator in matlab

Tags: matlab, gyrator

I am new to matlab , i am trying to simulate a simple circuit to check my calculation I have done on paper.

The circuit is the following, it has a gyrator and couple resistors.1 amp is flowing into the circuit.**You can see the node names on matlab picture.**
[image]

I got the following equations:

[image]

Solved with calculator:

[image]

The results:

[image]

I built the circuit in matlab simulink but i got different results there. I am pretty sure missing something.
Here is the matlab circuit:
[image]

Values for the resistors and gyrator set correctly, the names show the resistors resistance. Gyrator conductance set :3.141592654

My problem is that i get different values for the nodes' potential not even close to that i have calculated.

So if you canfind what i am missing please tell me.
Thank you

Comment: If solver A doesn't equal solver B then make a very, very simple circuit to solve and it should be obvious which method is correct.

Comment: What are \$\gamma\$ and \$\psi\$ suppose to represent? There's inconsistent notation in your equations. You appear to be switching variables.

Comment: @Andy aka  I have used matlab for solving a circuit that had more components then this. I am almost certain ,becaused i checked couple times ,that i didn't miss calculated or something. The problem is in my matlab skills .

Comment: @KingDuken Sorry for the various names for the variables. The psi and phi represents node potential relatively to 0V. I used psi on the calculator and phi on the matlab and the hand drawed circuit. Sorry for that .

Comment: @KingDuken I suppose the thing you think is  a gamma that is actually is the gyrator conductance ,little r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you missed the units of the gyrator. Your calculations were for resistance while the simscape gyrator is in Siemens

So you need to enter \$\frac{1}{\pi}\$ instead of \$\pi\$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! That solved the problem and now the simulation shows the calculated results : )